# Colcon build unsuccessful

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-humble

I'm trying to build an old package. I'm not able to build the package successfully. Here is the repo for the trial. I'm using ROS2-humble

```
https://github.com/gokulp01/ros2-ublox-zedf9p.git
```

I would like to share my error for reference.

````
                 from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/ublox_firmware.hpp:9,
                 from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/src/ublox_firmware6.cpp:21:
/home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/gps.hpp:43:10: fatal error: ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp: No such file or directory
   43 | #include <ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/component_interface.hpp:35,
                 from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/ublox_firmware.hpp:9,
                 from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/src/ublox_firmware.cpp:7:
/home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/gps.hpp:43:10: fatal error: ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp: No such file or directory
   43 | #include <ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/build.make:244: CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/src/ublox_firmware6.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/build.make:230: CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/src/ublox_firmware.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/src/hpg_rov_product.cpp:13:
/home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/gps.hpp:43:10: fatal error: ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp: No such file or directory
   43 | #include <ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/src/tim_product.cpp:14:
/home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/gps.hpp:43:10: fatal error: ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp: No such file or directory
   43 | #include <ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/build.make:146: CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/src/hpg_rov_product.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/build.make:216: CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/src/tim_product.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/ublox_firmware8.hpp:16,
                 from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/src/ublox_firmware9.cpp:9:
/home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/gps.hpp:43:10: fatal error: ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp: No such file or directory
   43 | #include <ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/build.make:286: CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/src/ublox_firmware9.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/ublox_firmware7.hpp:16,
                 from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/src/ublox_firmware7.cpp:14:
/home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/gps.hpp:43:10: fatal error: ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp: No such file or directory
   43 | #include <ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/component_interface.hpp:35,
                 from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/hpg_ref_product.hpp:12,
                 from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/src/hpg_ref_product.cpp:15:
/home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/gps.hpp:43:10: fatal error: ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp: No such file or directory
   43 | #include <ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/ublox_firmware8.hpp:16,
                 from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/src/ublox_firmware8.cpp:16:
/home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/gps.hpp:43:10: fatal error: ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp: No such file or directory
   43 | #include <ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/build.make:132: CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/src/hpg_ref_product.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/component_interface.hpp:35,
                 from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/adr_udr_product.hpp:20,
                 from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/src/adr_udr_product.cpp:20:
/home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/gps.hpp:43:10: fatal error: ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp: No such file or directory
   43 | #include <ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/build.make:258: CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/src/ublox_firmware7.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/build.make:272: CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/src/ublox_firmware8.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/src/adr_udr_product.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/src/raw_data_product.cpp:11:
/home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/gps.hpp:43:10: fatal error: ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp: No such file or directory
   43 | #include <ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/build.make:202: CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/src/raw_data_product.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/hp_pos_rec_product.hpp:14,
                 from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/src/hp_pos_rec_product.cpp:14:
/home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/gps.hpp:43:10: fatal error: ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp: No such file or directory
   43 | #include <ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/build.make:118: CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/src/hp_pos_rec_product.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/component_interface.hpp:35,
                 from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/adr_udr_product.hpp:20,
                 from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/src/node.cpp:58:
/home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/gps.hpp:43:10: fatal error: ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp: No such file or directory
   43 | #include <ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/build.make:174: CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/src/node.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/src/gps.cpp:44:
/home/fire/src/ros2-ublox-zedf9p/ublox_gps/include/ublox_gps/gps.hpp:43:10: fatal error: ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp: No such file or directory
   43 | #include <ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/build.make:104: CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/src/gps.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:141: CMakeFiles/ublox_gps.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< ublox_gps [0.62s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 2 packages finished [5.83s]
  1 package failed: ublox_gps
  1 package had stderr output: ublox_gps
  1 package not processed```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. 

Thank you in advance
Adithya
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ublox_msgs/serialization.hpp` is part of the repository you provided. How do you build your workspace? `colcon build` considers the dependencies and would have built the ublox_msgs package before.

Comment: I'm building the workspace using ```colcon build --symlink-install``` and leaving the dependencies like defined in repository. When I tried to build the package. I understood that there is a problem with dependencies. Can you please share the proper declaration..? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a dependency (`ublox_msgs`) that hasn't been built yet. Check the CMakeLists.txt and package.xml files to make sure that dependency is properly listed.

Comment: When I tried to build the package. I understood that there is a problem with dependencies. Can you please share the proper declaration..?  Thanks

Comment: The proper declaration is, of course, package dependent. You can look at many examples online, but you'll need to dig through your package to determine how things should be built.

You mentioned that you're trying to update an older package. The format of the information you need may have changed in the ROS versions, but you should be able to resolve that with a little digging and online references.